# Equivalent of fmodf in C#?

Tags: c#, c, fmodf

In <strike>C++</strike> C: Output: "1610612736"

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", fmodf(5.6f, 6.4f));
    getchar();
}
```

In C#: Output: "5.6"

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(5.6f % 6.4f);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Clearly not the same output. Suggestions?

Comment: %d is for decimal. If you are using C++ use streams to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: btw this is C code, not C++. In C++ one uses `<cmath>`, `<cstdio>` and `std::fmod`.

Comment: @ Alexandre C: Its tagged as C++.

Comment: This post shouldn't be tagged as "FMOD", this tag is regarding the cross-platform audio middleware called FMOD, not the floating point modulus function.

Comment: Thanks for editing my post and changing the tab. I wanted to tag it as "fmodf", only this tag does not exist and I don't have enough reputation to create it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `printf("%f\n", fmodf(5.6f, 6.4f))` instead.

Comment: Good, sorry about the fact that it's C and tagged C++, I actually am coding in C# and only used the C version to compare.

Comment: @Lazlo: So you don't mind if I edit your original post then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the decimal problem with fprintf()

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << fmodf(5.6f, 6.4f) << std::endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Output 5.6

Comment: Please use <cmath> and <cstdio>, I'm quite sure the C headers trigger errors (or deprecation warnings at the very least) on most compilers. And please use the overloaded function `std::fmod` instead of C's `fmodf`.